# How to get an auto-generated id by using add()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am using node, vue, firestore.

I want to go to a page where the url is the auto-generated id of the document when I click on a document created using add().

I used to

```
setup () {
const moveToCreate = () => {
  router.push({
    name: 'Boadrdid',
    params: {
     id: Boardid
   }
  })
 }
}                          boardid.vue


{
  path: '/board/:id',
  name: 'Boardid',
  component: Boardid,
  props: true
}                          router/index.js
```

to move page, but Is there any other way than this one?

I want to get auto-generated id
Because to use db.collection.doc(   what should i do here    ).delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the way you did in your code:

```
router.push({name: 'Boadrdid', params: { id: Boardid }})
```

Or in a shorter way:

```
const id = 12;
router.push({name: 'Boadrdid', params: { id }})
```

Or this way:

```
const id = 12;
router.push({ path: `/board/${id}` })
```

You can read more about Vue programmatic navigation in this link https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html

Comment: What is const id = 12;  ?

Comment: Just an example of id (:

Comment: thank you answer for me but I need to use db.collection.doc( what should i do ).delete. so I should know id